# It is as simple as ABC

Tags: alphametic

Find three different digits $ A, B, C $ that satisfies the equation                                                              $ \overline{ABC} \times \overline{AA} \times \overline{AB} \times C = \overline{ABCABC}. $

Comment: Is (AA) a concatonation of A rather than a multiplication? (i.e. $11\times A$ rather than $A^{2}$?)

Comment: Thx for the edit..still learning the correct lingo for precise posting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> $ABCABC=1001\times ABC$. $1001=7\times11\times13$. So $A=1, B=3, C=7$ is the soution.